# Why is the curl of a vector field a pseudovector?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, vector-fields

There is an invariant definition of curl operation:

$rotA = (*d(A^b))^{\text#}$ , where: A - vector field, * - hodge star, and  $^\text#$ / $^b$ - lowering/raising the index.

Acording this, $rotA$ is correctly definded vector field. But in euclidean space rot operation is exspressed as:

$rotA = [\nabla,A]$

And there is a problem: if we do the mirror transformation ($\textbf r' = -\textbf r$), $rotA$ not change:

$A' = -A, \nabla' = - \nabla, (rotA)' = rotA$

But if $rotA$ is vector it must got a negativ sign.

What is wrong here?

p.s. the mirror transformation is isometry of euclidean space.

Comment: Your finding is precisely why $rot A$ is not a vector-field.

Comment: Yes. We have an invariant definition that says rotA is vector-field. And there is a problem.

Comment: The problem is that your expression is not as invariant as you would have thought: The hodge star is the problem: Wikipedia on the hode star: "the Hodge star provides an isomorphism between axial vectors and bivectors". 

That's probably a sloppy way to put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following, I'm going to use the term *curl* instead of *rot* because it's more familiar to me. There are a few different ways one could answer your question.  If you take your abstract definition
$$\mathrm{curl}(A):= (\star(d\mathbf A^\flat))^\sharp\equiv \nabla \times \mathbf A$$
then $\mathrm{curl}(A)$ is a the extra minus sign arises because the definition utilizes the Hodge dual and you're working in an odd number of dimensions.

---

As a brief review, consider the exterior algebra $\bigwedge V$ over an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$.  The space of $k$-vectors is $n\choose k$-dimensional, immediately suggesting a correspondence between $k$-vectors and $(n-k)$-vectors, which can be formalized using the Hodge star operator.  There are several approaches to this$^\ddagger$; I will describe the one most common in the physics literature.

If $V$ is equipped with an inner product $(\cdot,\cdot):V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb R$, then we can consider an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ (we don't *need* an orthonormal basis, but it's convenient for this quick description). This choice of basis defines an $n$-form $e_1\wedge\ldots\wedge e_n$. Given a $k$-vector $a$ of the form $a=e_{i_1}\wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_k}$, we define $\star a$ to be the unique $(n-k)$-form such that $a\wedge (\star a) = e_1\wedge \ldots \wedge e_n$.  This is then extended by linearity to all $k$-vectors, and then to the entire exterior algebra.

From this perspective, the duality provided by $\star$ is an entirely basis-dependent notion.  Consider $V=\mathbb R^3$ and some orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.  Let $A=e_1$ be a vector and $B=e_2\wedge e_3$ be a 2-vector (also called a *bivector*).  Then $\star B = e_1 = A$.  If we switch to a new basis $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ where $f_i=-e_i$, then we find straightforwardly that $A = -f_1$ and $B= f_2\wedge f_3$.  **However**, the new $n$-form for computing the Hodge dual becomes $f_1\wedge f_2 \wedge f_3=-e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3$ (i.e. the orientation of the new basis is opposite the old one), and so $\star B = f_1 = - A$.

In words, $k$-vectors like $A$ and $B$ are basis independent objects; under a change of basis, the components change such that the $k$-vectors themselves remain invariant.  In contrast, $\star B$ is a vector *in a given basis*, but *which* vector it is depends on which basis we're using. Under orientation-preserving changes of basis it transforms like a vector, but when the orientation is reversed it gets an extra minus sign because it is literally becoming a different vector.  Such objects are called *pseudo*vectors to emphasize this distinction.

---

The above formalism generalizes straightforwardly to the cotangent bundle to some manifold and the associated exterior algebra of forms. Once we have that, then the answer to your question is straightforward:

$$A \rightarrow A^\flat \rightarrow dA^\flat \rightarrow \star dA^\flat \rightarrow (\star dA^\flat)^\sharp$$

$$\mathrm{vector}\rightarrow \mathrm{1\ form}\rightarrow \mathrm{2\ form}\rightarrow \mathrm{pseudo\ 1\ form} \rightarrow \mathrm{pseudovector}$$

---

To put this in a more physical context, the curl is a pseudovector because it measures the circulation of a vector field around an infinitesimal loop.  Such a loop defines a surface, and it is to that **surface** which the circulation most naturally refers.

However, via the right-hand rule (which can be understood as a physical manifestation of the Hodge duality) we can define a correspondence between (oriented) surfaces and vectors.  By this correspondence, we can frame this "average circulation" as a "vector" field rather than a [bivector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector) field, but (for the reasons discussed above) it is not a true vector field but rather a *pseudo*vector field.  It is the correspondence between surfaces and their normal vectors - or more abstractly, the correspondence between $k$-forms and $(d-k)$-forms - through which the pseudovector/pseudoform transformation behavior enters the picture.

For what it's worth, this subtlety can be avoided by defining
$$\mathrm{curl}(\mathbf A) := (d\mathbf A^\flat)^\sharp \equiv \nabla \wedge \mathbf A$$
to be a bivector field, but this is less familiar to most students.  It's personally my preferred perspective, but your mileage may vary.

---

$^\ddagger$In this approach, we compute the Hodge dual by referencing the orientation of the basis we use. The standard approach in the mathematics literature, as far as I am aware, is to endow the space $V$ itself with a basis-independent orientation at the outset, and then compute the Hodge dual with respect to that. I suspect because physicists tend to work and think at the level of coordinate charts and components, we have a strong bias against choosing global, basis-independent conventions like a choice of orientation for the space, preferring instead to work as locally as possible.

Comment: so, using standard coordinates on $\Bbb{R}^3$, we have $dy\wedge dz$ is a $2$-form, and $*(dx) = dy\wedge dz$ is also a 2-form. SO, it's not clear to me what you mean by "an organic 2-form" versus "those which arise via a Hodge duality". Afterall, they're the same section of the same vector bundle  ($\bigwedge^2(T^*\Bbb{R}^3)$) over $\Bbb{R}^3$, so how can they be different things?

Comment: @user580918 I've substantially updated my answer.  The point is that $*(dx)= dy\wedge dz$ is a basis-dependent statement in the standard physics convention.  If we switch orientations, then $*(dx) = \color{red}{-}dy\wedge dz$.  In that sense, while $dy\wedge dz$ is a well-defined 2-form, $(*dx)$ acts like a 2-form given one choice of orientation but transforms to a *different* 2-form when that orientation is reversed.

Comment: I think your last paragraph kind of gets at the difference  between the way we are viewing things. To me a Hodge-star is defined on an oriented, pseudo-innerproduct space $(V,g,\text{Or})$. Of course, there are no canonical choices for an orientation (defined either as an equivalence class of ordered basis, or a volume form), neither are there any canonical choices for $g$.  But once we make this choice, $\star$ is a perfectly well-defined map from $\bigwedge^k(V^*)\to \bigwedge^{n-k}(V^*)$. But, why anyone would want to switch orientations in the middle of a discussion is beyond me.

Comment: So, yes I completely agree that if you initially call $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ positively oriented then $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is oppositely oriented, which is precisely why I would either avoid working with this ordered basis, or atleast I'd reorder it say $\{f_1,f_3,f_2\}$ to match the original orientation (and if you prefer, give it new names $f_1':=f_1, f_2':=f_3, f_3':=f_2$ and work with $\{f_1',f_2',f_3'\}$). So, ok, I think we both agree on the underlying mathematics, but due to linguistic phrasing differences or whatever I had a slight confusion about what you were talking about initially.

Comment: @user580918 Yes, I think you're right. In terms of motivation for the convention I discuss, defining $\star$ relative to the orientation of a local coordinate patch rather than a globally defined orientation for the manifold becomes particularly useful when the manifold is non-orientable; this can be formalized more abstractly in the language of [twisted forms](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+form#twisted), which apparently de Rham called "forms of odd type."